# Basic questions about scilab

Tags: scilab

I am taking a numeric calculus class and we are not required to know any scilab programming except the very basic, which is taught through a booklet, since the class is mostly theoretical. I was reading the booklet and found this scilab code meant to find a root of a function through bissection method. 
The problem is, I can't find a way to make it work. I tried to call it with `bissecao(x,-1,1,0.1,40)` however it didn't work.
The error I got was:

```
at line     3 of function bissecao ( E:\Downloads\bisseccao3.sce line 3 )

Invalid index.
```

As I highly doubt that the code itself isn't working, and I tried to search for anything I could spot that seemed wrong, to no avail, I guess I am probably calling it wrong, somehow.

The code is the following:

```
function p = bissecao(f, a, b, TOL, N)
i = 1
fa = f(a)
while (i <= N)
  //iteraction of the bissection
  p = a + (b-a)/2
  fp = f(p)
  //stop condition
  if ((fp == 0) | ((b-a)/2 < TOL)) then
    return p
    end
  //bissects the interval
  i = i+1
  if (fa * fp > 0) then
    a = p
    fa = fp
    else
    b = p
    end
  end
error ('Max number iter. exceded!')
endfunction
```

Where f is a function(I guess), a and b are the limits of the interval in which we will be iterating, TOL is the tolerance at which the program terminates close to a zero, and N is the maximum number of iteractions.

Any help on how to make this run is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your error log does not match mine : your call of `bissecao` involve `x` as the first parameter, which is not defined in your question. Please defined it clearly: did you mean the identity function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Error in bissecao

The only error your `bissecao` function have is the call to `return` :

> In a function `return` stops the execution of the function,
>   `[x1,..,xn]=return(a1,..,an)` stops the execution of the function and
>   put the local variables `ai` in calling environment under names `xi`.

So you should either call it without any argument (input our output) and the function will exit and return p.
Or you could call `y1 = return(p)` and the function will exit and `p` will be stored in `y1`.

It is better to use the non-arguments form `return` in functions to avoid changing values of variables in the parent/calling script/functions (possible side-effect).

The argument form is more useful when interactively debugging with `pause`:

> In pause mode, it allows to return to lower level.
>   `[x1,..,xn]=return(a1,..,an)` returns to lower level and put the local
>   variables `ai` in calling environment under names `xi`.

## Error in calling bissecao

The problem may come by your call: `bissecao(x,-1,1,0.1,40)` because you didn't defined `x`. Just fixing this by creating a function solves the problem:

```
function y=x(t)
  y=t+0.3
enfunction
x0=bissecao(x,-1,1,0.1,40) // changed 'return p' to 'return'
disp(x0) // gives -0.3 as expected
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `t` instead of `x`in the definition of `x(t)`?

Comment: @luispauloml Forgot it. Fixed it.